# django-haystack relevants suggestions

Tags: django, django-haystack

I'm using Django-haystack + Elasticsearch. I have INCLUDE_SPELLING set to True and {{ suggestion }} tag in my template.
When for example I search for émile zola I get émile zozo (which doesn't exist in the index or db) as suggestion instead of emile zola.
Anyway to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [`set-spelling-query`](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/searchqueryset_api.html?highlight=suggestion#set-spelling-query) method?

Comment: I tried but nothing